# How do I know if an application uses Silverlight?

Tags: xaml, silverlight

I am looking at a legacy .NET application and need to know if it is using Silverlight.  If it is, I need to migrate the code to WPF, XAML, or HTML5.

Is there a specific set of namespaces and references that tell me that this is a Silverlight application?

Answer (score 0):

Some indicators:

- the `ProjectTypeGuids` element in the .csproj/.vbproj files contains the Silverlight project GUID: `{A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}`
- the `System.*` dependencies, when observed in the property grid in Visual Studio, would have version `5.0.5.0` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a Silverlight project property with bellow link

[Silverlight project property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiOh7.png)